# IE8 expected ']' in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting error in regexp in IE8. Other browsers work ok, but on IE8 I'm getting error:

```
IE8 expected ']' in regular expression
```

in line:

```
src.replace(/\/([^]+)\//g, '/big/$1');
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Here you can se the result:

http://regexr.com?38bil

Comment: unfortunately, when i escape ^ it returns wrong value.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need then `\/(.+?)\/`. Why an empty negated character class?

Comment: What are you trying to match? Can you provide sample input and output? The link in the OP gives a blank page with error messages (far better to post information here than on other sites that may or may not work and may disappear long before this post does).

Comment: @RobG: He posted regexr example, he's matching urls

Comment: @elclanrs It would still be preferred to have that inside the question :) especially because that website loads like crap through a colander.

Comment: @elclanrs–the link he posted doesn't work for me, it just shows "RSL Error 101" and "Error #2032". Far better to just post here, especially if it's that simple.

Comment: @RobG: Weird, works fine and fast for me. But I agree, example in the question would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using `[^]` to match every possible character. You can use `[\s\S]` instead. See [What is meaning of [^] in Javascript regexps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843428/what-is-meaning-of-in-javascript-regexps).

Comment: You have the best answer. Infact `.+` (suggested in comments above) does not match line feeds.

Comment: To be fair, I only posted an alternative for `[^]`. Depending on what the OP really wants to match, there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this regex:

```
\/([^\/]+)\/
```

You're using `[^]+` which may not work with all regex engines as there should by a character following `^` (for negation) in character class.

Comment: I think whether or not `[^]` is correct depends on the underlying engine. At least on regexr (see the OPs link) it treats it like `not matching ''`, while other tools (like regex101) throw an error. Interesting, though...

Comment: According to the ES5 sepcficiation, `[^]` is valid: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.1. It means "match none of the empty character set", which basically means "match any character".

Comment: How do we know if IE8 is 100% compliant with ECMA specs :) Better not to rely on a suspicious feature which is NOT supported by majority of regex engines.

Comment: That's not what I meant with my comment. Obviously it doesn't work in IE8, otherwise it wouldn't throw an error. But your statement *"You're using `[^]+` which is definitely wrong regex "* is incorrect.